# httpd virtual hosts redirecting to default installation page

Tags: php, virtualhost, httpd

i defined

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/andrei06041990/sites/cosmeticremix"
    ServerName cosmeticremix.dev
    ServerAlias www.cosmeticremix.dev
    <Directory "/home/andrei06041990/sites/cosmeticremix">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride All
        AllowOverride None
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

at the end of the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file
but when i access `http://www.cosmeticremix.dev/` in browser i end up with the default page of the apache server
how are virtual hosts defined?

Comment: my cosmeticremix is not empty and has an index.php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention Directive options in your httpd.conf file.
Apache (httpd.conf), search for DirectoryIndex and replace the line with this #Note: will only work if you have dir_module enabled, but that's default on most installs.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If you use other directory indexes, list them in order of preference i.e.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
```